# How to bind 3 inputs values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 inputs and need by entering value in first input two others recalculate their values each time when I change value in first input.
X - should be entered by user, y = X * X, z = X / 2

```
<label>X</label>
   <input value={x} onChange={this.handleChange} />

<label>Y</label>
   <input value={y} onChange={this.handleChange} />

<label>Z</label>
   <input value={z} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to `React` World. You need to use one `state` value to save `x` value.

```
state={
   x: 0,
}
handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({ x:  e.target.value});
}
...
render() {
const { x } = this.state;
...
<label>X</label>
   <input value={x} onChange={this.handleChange} />

<label>Y</label>
   <input value={x * x} readOnly} />

<label>Z</label>
   <input value={x / 2} readOnly} />
}
```

If you update the first `input` value, that value will be saved in `x` state value. That makes `rerender` your component.

According to your question *How to bind 3 inputs values?*,

If you need to bind multiple `input` changes with one function, you can pass unique Id to `handleChange` function.

```
handleChange = (e, inputId) => {
   if (inputId === 0) {
      this.setState({ x: e.target.value });
   } else if(inputId === 1) {
      this.setState({ y: e.target.value });
   } else if(inputId === 2) {
      this.setState({ z: e.target.value });
   }

}
...
<input value={x} onChange={() => this.handleChange(0)} />
<input value={y} onChange={() => this.handleChange(1)} />
<input value={z} onChange={() => this.handleChange(2)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

in react you can use state and assign the state var to the value of y and z .

Answer (score 0):

you can use **state**, it helps you to **render your ui** whenever you need

```
<label>X</label>
   <input value={this.state.x} onChange={(input)=>this.setState(X:input)} />

<label>Y</label>
   <input value={this.state.y} onChange={(input)=>this.setState(y:input)} />

<label>Z</label>
   <input value={this.state.z} onChange={(input)=>this.setState(z:input)} />
```

or

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
        y: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
    };
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }
```

and then use onpress function like this:

```
onPress={(input) => this.onPress(input)}
```